# solving two simple line integrals

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

First one is : $$\int_\gamma e^zdz,\quad \gamma(t)=\pi ti,\quad t\in[-1,1]$$ 
my attempt:
$z=\gamma(t)=\pi ti \quad dz=\pi idt \quad -1\le t\ \le1, $ then

$$\int_\gamma e^zdz=\int_{-1}^1e^{\pi ti}\pi idt=\pi i\int_{-1}^1e^{\pi ti}dt=\pi i|_{-1}^1\frac{e^{\pi ti}}{\pi i}=e^{\pi i}-e^{-\pi i}.$$
Is this correct?

Second one is:
$$\int_\gamma z^2dz\quad \gamma(t)=t+it\quad t\in [0,1] $$ I tried to solve with the way i tried like in $1$st, but couldn't solve.

Comment: Careful: $$z=\pi ti\implies dz=\pi idt\ldots$$ though later, in the integral, you put the right expression. BTW, $$0=-1-(-1)=e^{\pi i}-e^{-\pi i}=2i\sin \pi=0$$

Comment: Can you indicate where you're lost on the second?

Comment: @DonAntonio my mistake. fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second integral is equal to

$$I_2=\int_0^1 (t+it)^2 (1+i)dt=\int_0^1 t^2(1+i)^3dt=(1+i)^3\cdot\frac{1}{3}, $$

as $\frac{d\gamma}{dt}=1+i$.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is correct, and you can do the second one in the same way.

However, there is a much faster approach. In both examples, your integrand has an (easy to find) antiderivative, and the (complex version of) the fundamental theorem of calculus gives you very short and simple solutions.

More precisely, in your first integral, $e^z$ is an anti-derivative of $e^z$ and the curve goes from $-i\pi$ to $i\pi$. Hence the integral evaluates to $e^{i\pi} - e^{-i\pi} = 0$.